# Conditional cloudpagesURL 400 bad request

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

I am sending recipients to a cloudpage from an email.

I have written conditional logic to pass through the values `email_address` or `membernumber` when a user clicks the link.

My code is giving me a 400 bad request. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Note: `email_address` and `membernumber` fields exist in the sendable Data Extension

```ampscript
%%[
    VAR @url, @adviserEmail, @adviserMember

    SET @Email = AttributeValue("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    SET @member_number = AttributeValue("MEMBER_NUMBER")

    IF NOT Empty(@Email) THEN
        SET @url = "%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(111,'EMAIL_ADDRESS',@Email))=%%"
    ELSEIF NOT Empty(@member_number) THEN
        SET @url = "%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(111,'MEMBER_NUMBER',@member_number))=%%"
    ENDIF
    ]%%

<a href="%%=v(@url)=%%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `@url` output doesn't execute the code but give you the string since you set the `@url` variable as a string.

The correct way to do is setting the `@url` with `CloudPagesURL` function first then you put the AMPscript code in your HTML code line. Try something like this:

```ampscript
%%[
    VAR @url, @adviserEmail, @adviserMember

    SET @Email = AttributeValue("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    SET @member_number = AttributeValue("MEMBER_NUMBER")

    IF NOT Empty(@Email) THEN
        SET @url = CloudPagesURL(111,'EMAIL_ADDRESS',@Email)
    ELSEIF NOT Empty(@member_number) THEN
        SET @url = CloudPagesURL(111,'MEMBER_NUMBER',@member_number)
    ENDIF
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%">Your CTA button</a>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help!